# Researches on 'Ontology of the Subject' with a focus on Lacan

Tags: reference-request, ontology, lacan

I'm looking for essays about "Lacan's Ontology of the subject" .  The point is the formation of them. So, It's like writing a report about the researches already made on "Lacan's Ontology of the subject".

How can i find these kinds of essays on the internet? Is there a specific website for these psychoanalytical researches? (Something like "sciencedirect")

Answer (score 1):

[Philpapers](https://philpapers.org/) is a collection of papers having to do with philosophy, although you are very likely to run into pay walls most of the time, as is common with most academic paper repositories. Searching for your topic returns [these results](https://philpapers.org/s/Lacan%27s%20Ontology%20of%20the%20subject).

There is the [*American Journal of Psychoanalysis*](http://www.springer.com/psychology/journal/11231) but again you will end up running into pay walls trying to access specific articles. I would suggest you talk to your university and see if you can get access through them.

Additionally, there are many websites devoted to the study of Lacan's psychoanalysis that may contain useful information for you. See:

> [lacan.org](http://lacan.org/)
>
> [lacan.com](http://www.lacan.com/)
>
> [londonsociety-nls.org.uk](http://londonsociety-nls.org.uk/)
>
> [lacanschool.org](http://www.lacanschool.org/)